# How do I login to Ubuntu directly using root account?

Tags: login-screen

How do I login to Ubuntu 15.10 directly using root account?

Comment: Please give some context: it depends what you mean by *"login"* and it depends what you mean by *"directly"*. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Hi, what i would like to do is to enter from the login screen when i start my pc so that I see root as user an then I enter the password which i have already set thru # sudo passwd root. Sorry i was not very specific first. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: There are two reasons root login is disabled. First, it is insecure. Second it is unnecessary.

Comment: If you want to use a system with root Ubuntu is not your operating system and  try Fedora, CentOS or SUSE. Debian based systems use "sudo".

Comment: @Rinzwind `sudo` is not Debian-specific. Most *nix systems use it (e.g. Mac OS X). And as far as I'm aware, most Linux systems recommend against root login.

Answer (score 4):

Root account is disabled in Ubuntu for login by default. You would have to change root password to login directly.

Personally i suggest you login to root through your sudo account with `sudo -i`

Comment: Hi Serg, Thanks for your info. But is it possible to have root as a user in the login screen when you first enter Ubuntu OS? How can I do this? please tell me the steps, Thanks

Comment: So login to GUI with root . . . possible but not recommended, because you are going to be running the whole graphical environnment as root  . . .which means security holes possible

Comment: HI Serg,That's right. even if it implies security holes i'd like to try.

Comment: Running a desktop as root will break it for the user used to install the system. If you want to use a root user use another operating system like Fedora, CentOS or SUSE and not a Debian based system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can login as a root user however this is in no way suggested.
 I would also recommend `sudo -i` to emulate root. However this being Linux you can do as you wish and enable root. **This can cause major security holes and is not recommend!** `sudo passwd root` create a password and now you can login as `root.` To disable root `sudo passwd -dl root`

[You can read more about root access here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Answer (score 0):

Single user mode will work, assuming your root account has a password.

At grub, choose Advanced. Cursor to kernel you want. Then "e" to edit grub stanza and change linux line to end "ro single". This is about 8 lines down usually longest line. Cut out silent and splash if they are on end. Then "x" launch system boot to prompt that asks for root password. There will be a reminder on how to launch at bottom of screen. I'm not sure if Alt-x might be needed (for sure, there is an x )

If you really mean to ask this question, this is the right answer. I don't know why somebody gave you the -1 on this. It is a reasonable question. You should not have to give anybody "context" for this one.

Other answers seem to assume you are a moron. This part is not for novices. If you are, step back from it.

Also, ignore Ubuntu chorus 'there is no root user'. That's just silly. His home folder is /root.  Giving that account  a password is easy and it does nothing harmful AT ALL. @Rinzwind is not correct on that point. sudo will still work from user account .

Answer (score 0):

First: There are legitimate reasons to log in as root, like when you are moving or archiving the location of your /home directory, and you don't want any artefacts or broken pipes from being logged in as a user.

Coming from OpenSUSE, not being able to log in as root definitely is not an improvement but a rather a nuisance.

Second: While Ubuntu succeeds in making logging in to the GUI difficult, at least under X11 you can use a command line console session rather easily after making sure, root has a password.

1. `sudo passwd root`.
2. Log out.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> for a console session.
4. Log in as root in the console session.

You can now use a genuine root command-shell with /root being your $HOME and no users logged into your system. Also, the security holes speculated about by other posters do not exist in this setup, because the X-Server doesn't run.

After having finished your console session, log out with `exit` or Ctrl-D, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to go to the login prompt, log in again and continue your normal GUI life.

Answer (score -1):

If you need login as root :
Open terminal then type

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Find line `[security]`
and replace to

```
[security]
AllowRoot=true
```

Save and exit.
And run

```
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/gdm-password
```

Then replace this `auth required pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success`

To `#auth required pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success`

Save and exit
And restart computer.